# Parallel std::fill has different performance on different architectures; why?

Tags: c++, c++11, architecture, parallel-processing, lambda

I'm attempting to write a parallel vector fill, using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std; 
using namespace std::chrono;

void fill_part(vector<double> & v, int ii, int num_threads)
{
  fill(v.begin() + ii*v.size()/num_threads, v.begin() +   (ii+1)*v.size()/num_threads, 0);
}

int main()
{
  vector<double> v(200*1000*1000);

  high_resolution_clock::time_point t = high_resolution_clock::now();
  fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
  duration<double> d = high_resolution_clock::now() - t;
  cout << "Filling the vector took " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(d).count()
       << " ms in serial.\n";

  unsigned num_threads = thread::hardware_concurrency() ? thread::hardware_concurrency() :  1;

  cout << "Num threads: " << num_threads << '\n';
  vector<thread> threads;
  t = high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(int ii = 0; ii< num_threads; ++ii)
  {
    threads.emplace_back(fill_part, std::ref(v), ii, num_threads);
  }
  for(auto & t : threads)
  {
    if(t.joinable()) t.join();
  }
  d = high_resolution_clock::now() - t;
  cout << "Filling the vector took " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(d).count()
       << " ms in parallel.\n";
}
```

I tried this code on four different architectures (all Intel CPUs--but no matter).

The first I tried had 4 CPUs, and the parallelization gave no speedup. The second had 4, and was 4 times as fast, the third had 4, and was twice as fast, and the last had 2, and gave no speedup.

My hypothesis is that the differences arise because the RAM bus can either be saturated by a single CPU or not, but is this correct? How can I predict what architectures will benefit from this parallelization?

*Bonus question*: The `void fill_part` function is awkward, so I wanted to do it with a lambda:

```
 threads.emplace_back([&]{fill(v.begin() + ii*v.size()/num_threads, v.begin() + (ii+1)*v.size()/num_threads, 0); });
```

This compiles but terminates with a bus error; what's wrong with the lambda syntax?

Comment: For the bonus question, you take `ii` by reference, and its scope/lifetime is less than the thread. `[ii, &]` should fix the bus error (or `[&v, ii, num_threads]` to be similar to your first sample).

Comment: When you're just filling memory, a single core can usually saturate your bandwidth to memory. More threads is only likely to improve speed on machines with multiple sockets, each with its own channel to memory.

Comment: @Jarod42: You are exactly right--that worked. The strange thing is that the lambda takes twice as long to run as the function call when compiled with ``g++ -lpthread -O3`` (``g++-4.10``).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I've tried it on a machine with a single socket, and it was 4x as fast.